# How to get a ClearCase view into a command.com variable

Tags: dos, cleartool

I am writing some command.com scripts to automate some tasks involving ClearCase views.  I can use `cleartool lsview viewname` to determine if the view exists or not.  How can I get the output from the lsview subcommand into a variable such that the script does not get terminated  by a cleartool error when the view does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a recent enough ClearCase (7.1.x), you can also use:

```
cleartool lsview -quick -host <registryServer>|find "viewname"
```

(replace `<registryServer>` by your ClearCase registry server name)
In a DOS script, you would redirect that to a file, and then affect the content of said file to a variable:

```
set VAR=""
cleartool lsview -quick -host <registryServer>|find "viewname" > c:\temp\aview
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto noset
set /p VAR=<c:\temp\aview
:noset
```

You can put a condition on setting that VAR with `ERRORLEVEL` (test done just after the cleartool command).
The advantage is that the cleartool command doesn't generate any error message, even if the view doesn't exist.

Comment: Why am I not surprised to see who answered the question. :-)

Comment: @pajato0 well, nine years of ClearCase (2002, 2003, 7.0.x, 7.1.x) help ;) (plus some other VCS, and other tools. Currently, I am dealing with the new ClearCase entirely rewritten, called Jazz Source Control, shipped within IBM Rational Team Concert)